Wrong Row subtotal
enter image description here
As you can see in the screenshot above, the row subtotal for this specific date is not coming correctly. This is only happening for a specific date i.e 6/26/2024. For all the others values are correct.
The rows are coming from a table called "Target", the columns are from "EDW Dim Date" and the values are from "Combined Fact". I have verified and the data is present in the fact table. Below is the relationship viewenter image description here
The measure that I'm using in values is Completion # = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Combined Fact','Combined Fact'[Target Type]="Completed"))+0
I don't know what's wrong and have been stuck at it for 2 days.
First of all I've validated that the data is not missing. For a specific item the values are not being shown in the rows.
The fact table is a Union of two tables and when I try to directly connect to source tables the numbers are fine. But when I use the same measure with the "Target" table, it's coming wrong.

I think this is because you have some records in combined facts which are connected with some records in Edw DimUnit, which in turn do not have related  records in Target

could you pls provide the pbix file?

@ryan Yes. I can send over the file to you.

i am new here. Do we have private message in this community?
